# How to stop an image from automatically resizing when using autolayout in Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, css, iphone, xcode

So close to finishing my first app, just need some help solving this problem. I set all the constraints to suggested and it looks fine.

Only downside is the image on the iPhone 4 is too small as it gets resized automatically. The image also resizes on the iPhone 6 but looks ok as its bigger however, a few things around the image move towards the left of the screen instead of staying in the center.

Any ideas?

Image settings - http://i.imgur.com/tghutSj.png

Comment: Do you want to resize the image just in special cases or do you want to avoid resizing at all?

Comment: Avoid resizing at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your image is sized relative to the height of the containing view, it seems. You have Top space and Bottom space defined, and then Height is >=.

There are lot of ways to fix it, but you probably want to just add a constraint for Aspect Ratio (to itself) and remove the Height constraint. Might need to remove either the Top space or Bottom space one as well.

Comment: When removing either top or bottom constraint the image resizes so big that it goes off the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, just set a constraint for height equals 'x' and a constraint for width equals 'y'.

It might be helpful if you post a screenshot of your wanted layout and the positioning of the image.

Comment: I already have the heigh and width constraints set. This is my layout with image in middle - http://i.imgur.com/dT8Pitn.png